# Why won't the following useEffect() on AndroidPermissions work?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I think i have an issue running the following useEffect and useState related code in this particular class. Also when i import useEffect and useState in the very first line, both stay unhighlighted in my VS Code, like they're not in play.

Answer (score 1):

The hooks `useState` and `useEffect` (or hooks in general) only work in react-native functional components. The quickest way to fix this, would be to convert your class component to a functional component as follows.

```js
function CallingScreen(props) {
  
    const [permissionGranted, setPermissionGranted] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const getPermissions = async () => {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(permissions);
            const recordAudioGranted = granted[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO] == 'granted';
            const cameraGranted = granted[PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA] == 'granted'
            if(!cameraGranted || !recordAudioGranted) {
                Alert.alert('Permissions not granted');
            }
            else {
                setPermissionsGranted(true);
            }
        };

        if(Platform.OS == 'android') {
            getPermissions();
        }
        else {
            setPermissionGranted(true);
        }
        
    }, []);


        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#7b4e80' }}>


               Render Stuff...




            </SafeAreaView>
        )
}
```